# VBA code to only show rows that contain similar text to an input field?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and am trying to cobble together some code to allow a user to input a word (or several words) into a cell and then show a list of matching row entries.

I have tried the following code but am getting an "`instring = type mismatch`" error.

Note that "`B3`" is the field dedicated for the "search word" and column `F` is the column containing the text I want to search within. If the word is contained, I want to show that row and hide all rows that don't contain that word.

```
Sub Find_Possible_Task()

  ROW_NUMBER = 0
  SEARCH_STRING = Sheets("codeset").Range("B3")
  ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER + 1
  ITEM_IN_REVIEW = Sheets("codeset").Range("F:F")

  If InStr(ITEM_IN_REVIEW, SEARCH_STRING) Then
    Do
      Cells(c.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Loop Until ITEM_IN_REVIEW = ""
  End If

End Sub
```

TIA!

Comment: Hi there, I edited your question with some formatting, but please for future reference, use some indenting  in your code and stop putting empty newline after every line of code. It actively hurts the readability

Answer (score 0):

instead of instr(), consider range.find().

```
Sub Find_Possible_Task()

Dim SEARCH_STRING As String
Dim ITEM_IN_REVIEW As Range
Dim found As Range
Dim i As Integer

SEARCH_STRING = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
i = 1

Do
    Set ITEM_IN_REVIEW = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
    Set found = ITEM_IN_REVIEW.Find(What:=SEARCH_STRING)
    If found Is Nothing Then

        ITEM_IN_REVIEW.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop Until ITEM_IN_REVIEW = ""

End Sub
```

alternatively, consider using filter table:
1. check if your table has filter on ==> if yes, pass. if no, turn on filter.
2. filter column F for keyword to contain value in cell B3.

Comment: Thanks for the help, twenty49! This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Few bad coding conventions or even possibly downright errors:

1. It's a good practice to explicity declare the scope `Public/Private` of your `Sub` procedure
2. Unless you're passing the variables from some place else, they need to be declared with `Dim` keyword
3. Using `Option Explicit` will help you prevent aforementioned error(s)
4. (Subjective) variables in all caps are ugly and in most programming languages it is convention to reserve all caps variables names for constants (`Const`)

   ```
   Option Explicit
   Private Sub keep_matches()
     Dim what As Range
     Dim where As Range
     Dim res As Range ' result
     Dim lr As Long ' last active row
     Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("codeset")

     lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
     Set what = ws.Range("B3")
     Set where = ws.Range("F1:F" & lr)

     ' we'll create an extra column for a loop in our .Find method
     where.Copy
     ws.Range("F1").EntireColumn.Insert
     ws.Range("F1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     where.EntireRow.Hidden = True ' preemptively hide them all

     Set where = ws.Range("F1:F" & lr)
     Set res = where.Find(what, lookIn:=xlValues) ' ilook for matches, 1st attempt
     If Not res Is Nothing Then ' if found
        Do Until res Is Nothing ' repeat for all results
          res.EntireRow.Hidden = False
          res = "Checked"
          Set res = where.FindNext(res)
        Loop
     Else
        MsgBox("No matches were found")
        where.EntireRow.Hidden = False ' we don't wanna hide anything
     End If

     ws.Range("F1").EntireColumn.Delete ' remove the extra help column for Find method
   End Sub
   ```

Should work as expected.
If there are any question, let me know.